# CloudBees PostBuildTask plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, jenkins, cloudbees

I am working on Rails builds using Jenkins. I need deploy to Heroku after build is Green.

Locally I have used PostBuildScript plugin to execute shell commands and publish to Heroku:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin

Whoever, I can't see this plugin on CloudBeen plugin manager. isn't this plugin available with DEV@cloud accounts?

Is there any restriction from CloudBees on using this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've to raise a support ticket with CloudBees and they installed the plugin in for me. As per their support people, there are 2 type of plugin:

1. There are plugins that Jenkins admin can install to their account
2. There are some plugins that can be installed to your account, but, are not available in Plugin Manager, and anyone who want those plugins to be installed, has to request support.

PostBuild Task is one such plugin, and they installed it for me.